# animate.css failed with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want to put animations entrances and exits with jQuery and http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ :

```
jQuery(function($){


    function doOne() {
        $('#message').addClass("animated bounceOutLeft");
}

function doSlides() {       
   var msg = messages.shift();
   messages.push(msg);
    $('#message').html(msg).addClass("animated bounceInRight").delay(1000).addClass("animated bounceOutLeft", doSlides);
};

var messages = [
    "Message 1",
    "Message 2",
    "Message 3",
    "Message 4",
]; 

setTimeout(doOne, 3500);
setTimeout(doSlides, 4000);


    });
```

but there is a problem, animations failed :/ you can see that here : http://jsfiddle.net/z6rwr/13/

I try to put removeClass but nothing change. I try to separate functions : http://jsfiddle.net/z6rwr/14/ , same problem...

So, what is the correct way ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method like [addClass('className', callback)](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

```
addClass("animated bounceOutLeft", doSlides)
```

---

You can either do `addClass('className')` or `addClass(function(){})`

---

You could do like this:

```
.addClass(function(){
    $(this).addClass("animated bounceOutLeft");
    doSlides();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "SetTimeout" to "SetInterval". You call 'setInterval' with a function to execute and a period in milliseconds:

```
var messages = [
    "Message 1",
    "Message 2",
    "Message 3",
    "Message 4",
]; 

setInterval(doOne, 3500);
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/b9mGG/